# Recycler View Items Not loading using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

**ONStart Code**

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    DatabaseReference cartlistref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Cart");


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder>(
            Cart.class,
            R.layout.cart_items,
            CartViewHolder.class,
            cartlistref
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(CartViewHolder holder, Cart cart, int i) {
            holder.pname.setText(cart.getName());
            holder.pprice.setText(cart.getPrice());
            //holder.quantity.setNumber(cart.getQuantity());
        }
    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**CartViewHolder Code**

```
public class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
public TextView pname,pprice ;
public ImageView pimage;
public ElegantNumberButton quantity;
ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public CartViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    pname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pname);
    pprice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pprice);
    quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
    pimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pimage);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);
}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

}
**Cart items xml code**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pimage"
        android:layout_width="151dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/basket" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:text="Product Name"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Product price"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pprice"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
        <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/qty"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Cart Fragment code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hackathon.shoppy.fragments.CartFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rill"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalamt"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Total Amount = "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cartList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fancy:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/EditDetails"
        fancy:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fancy:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fancy:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rill"
        android:layout_above="@+id/checkout"/>

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/checkout"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        fancy:fb_defaultColor="#7ab800"
        fancy:fb_radius="10dp"
        fancy:fb_text="Proceed To Checkout"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Firebase Database Structure**
[Here is the firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElxXB.jpg)

*I have tried the above code*
*I want to load cart items of a specific user from the firebase database*
*The view is loading but the recycler view items arent showing up*
*Also the app is not crashing and no errors in logcat*

Comment: What card items do you want exactly to get? I only see a single node cart, right?

Comment: You're not calling `adapter.startListening()`, which means that the adapter never registers with Firebase to receive updates. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50679995/209103

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cartList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fancy:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/EditDetails"
    fancy:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    fancy:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    fancy:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rill"
    android:layout_above="@+id/checkout"/>
```

here is your problem. You are telling recycler view to WRAP CONTENT. problem is, that in moment of creation, content is empty, so recycler view has height zero.
Try to use

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

and experiment with height. But width for sure better to be left as match_parent

Comment: but why the content is empty ...as im loading cart items into that

Comment: you are loading them AFTER graphic element is created. In moment of creation, it is empty. Hence given command to 'wrap content' it wraps itself around nothing. Try my solution, if it works, please accept answer

Comment: is it working? my solution?

Comment: Yeah it worked ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of wrap content, try to fill color in recylerview with blue or something, if you are not able to see then change to match parent